# How to match a string value from the database with an integer value from the response

Tags: karate

My feature calls Java to query the database and then compares the results with the response. The results from the Java call returns all values as string. But in the response some of values are integer. So the test fails with the reason: actual value is not a string. I have tried to convert the results to json but that didn't work. If I print out the results, it shows all keys and values are enclosed in double quotes, but there are no double quotes in the error message. I found a similar question in the forum and it was suggested to set the field in the response to '#ignore'. But I want to verify all the fields. How do I get this to work?

```
Scenario: Get an script by id
* def results = db.getRows("select * from ScriptVersion where id=4 order by version")

Given path '4'
When method get
Then status 200
And match response.version == results  

[main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: path: $.version[0], actual: {id=4, version=1, created=2016-06-23T10:49:51.9630000-05:00, updated=2016-06-23T10:49:51.9630000-05:00, message=Initial Version, author=ocadm, hash=0023ad00455962eee4ef1db16a58ce41}, expected: {created=2016-06-23T10:49:51.9630000-05:00, author=ocadm, id=4, message=Initial Version, version=1, updated=2016-06-23T10:49:51.9630000-05:00, hash=0023ad00455962eee4ef1db16a58ce41}, reason: [path: $.version[0].id, actual: 4, expected: '4', reason: actual value is not a string]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert the fields you need to the right data type before the `match`:

```
* def results = [{ id: '1', foo: 'bar' }, { id: '2', foo: 'baz' }]
* def fun = function(x){ x.id = ~~x.id; return x }
* def results = karate.map(results, fun)
* match results == [{ id: 1, foo: 'bar' }, { id: 2, foo: 'baz' }]
```